# SSIS package items show up empty when I open project

Tags: ssis

I'm sorta new to SSIS packages and I've come across a problem.

I've taken over a project from a coworker who recently left. He zipped up his project and left it on his machine. The problem is that when I unzip and open the project on my machine, the data flow portion of the items is gone! Theres nothing there!

If, however, I unzip and open the project on his machine, all the stuff he put in is there. What the heck is going on?

Comment: And why wasn't it in Source control where everyone could get it? SSIS is code like any  other code and should be in Source control.

Comment: my company has wierd security rules. lets not get into that....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSIS packages are stored as XML. So no matter where you open it from, the package should open up - they may give you an error if components it needs are missing, but the data flow is not going to go AWOL just because it doesn't like your desktop wallpaper.

Maybe it is just a question of Zooming. On your machine, when the package opens up, right click in the yellow area, and from the context menu choose ZOOM and TO FIT

Other than that, I would verify the actual project path of each project in the solution on his workstation vs yours.